# Blender only showing a small sliver of objects in 3D View

Tags: 3d-view

Here is what the issue looks like:
[image: Blender 3d view issue]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by pressing View>Toggle Quad View, and then Toggling off quad view with the same menu

Comment: I have no idea whether this is a bug or some weird sliver-view mode, but toggling Quad view on and off fixed it for me too. 
Update: It's a feature called "clipping region." I must have hit 'ctrl+b' by mistake when I meant to just hit 'b' for a border selection.